# Search specific row in another table by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
SELECT * FROM #BH2

BookingID | Detail                                               | CreatedAgentCode | ChangeDate    
----------|------------------------------------------------------|------------------|--------------------------    
196162093 |  MRS LUCIENE CORREA correa MRS LUCIENE  CORREA       | lclisboa         | 2015-01-18 13:29:35.130
196162093 |  MRS LUCIENE CORREA LISBOA MRS LUCIENE CORREA correa | VOMATOS          | 2015-01-18 13:25:26.420
```

And this:

```
SELECT * FROM BookingPassengerVersion WHERE BookingID = 196162093  ORDER BY ModifiedDate DESC

BookingID | Title | FirstName | MiddleName | LastName | AgentCode |  ModifiedDate     
----------|-------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------    
196162093 |  MRS  | LUCIENE   |            | CORREA   | lclisboa  | 2015-01-18 13:29:35.130
196162093 |  MRS  | LUCIENE   | CORREA     | correa   | VOMATOS   | 2015-01-18 13:25:26.420
196162093 |  MRS  | LUCIENE   | CORREA     | LISBOA   | ADM       | 2015-01-12 18:01:09.503
196162093 |  MRS  | LUCIENE   | CORREA     | LISBOA   | ADM       | 2015-01-12 18:01:05.227
```

I need to add a new column to the `old name` and `new name`:

I tried this query:

```
BEGIN TRY DROP TABLE #FINAL_TABLE END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH
SELECT DISTINCT
       BH.BookingID,
       -- S OldName,
       (CASE WHEN _NewName.Title>'' THEN _NewName.Title+' ' ELSE '' END)+_NewName.FirstName+' '+ _NewName.MiddleName+' '+_NewName.LastName AS NewName,            
       BH.CreatedAgentCode, 
       BH.ChangeDate,
INTO   #FINAL_TABLE 
FROM   #BH2 BH

CROSS APPLY
(
     SELECT TOP 2
            Title
            , FirstName
            , MiddleName
            , LastName 
        FROM BookingPassengerVersion
      WHERE BookingID   = BH.BookingID  
        AND BH.ChangeDate = ModifiedDate
     ORDER BY ModifiedDate DESC
) _NewName
```

But I couldn't get this result:

```
BookingID | OldName                   | NewName                   | Detail                                              | CreatedAgentCode | ChangeDate    
----------|---------------------------|---------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------|------------------|--------------------------    
196162093 | MRS LUCIENE CORREA correa | MRS LUCIENE  CORREA       | MRS LUCIENE CORREA correa MRS LUCIENE  CORREA       | lclisboa         | 2015-01-18 13:29:35.130
196162093 | MRS LUCIENE CORREA LISBOA | MRS LUCIENE CORREA correa | MRS LUCIENE CORREA LISBOA MRS LUCIENE CORREA correa | VOMATOS          | 2015-01-18 13:25:26.420
```

Table `# BH2` has the `detail` column, this column is the `Old name` plus the `New name`.

I need the `old name` and the `new name` separated into two columns, so I'll use the `BookingPassengerVersion` table that has the change history.

The name is formed by adding the `title`, `first name`, `middle name` and `last name`.

Comment: Too lazy to add an answer, but check out this link: [How to Access the Previous Row and Next Row value in SELECT statement?](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/)

Comment: I really dont understand your question. `I need to add a new column to the old name and new name:` doesnt say to where you want to add. You need a query or you want add column to a table? For first you need to say what you want you query return. Also I suggest you create your schema in  http://sqlfiddle.com/ that will help us to see what you have

Comment: Table # BH2 has the detail column, this column is the Old name plus the new name.

I need the old name and the new name separated into two columns, so I'll use the BookingPassengerVersion table that has the change history.

The name is formed by adding the title, first name, middle name and last name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e8d2/1)

```
WITH cteBookingPassengerVersion AS
(
    SELECT  BookingID,
            RTRIM(
                CONCAT (
                    ISNULL(Title + ' ', ''),
                    ISNULL(FirstName + ' ', ''),
                    ISNULL(MiddleName + ' ', ''),
                    ISNULL(LastName, '')
                )
            ) AS NAME,
            ModifiedDate,
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY BookingID ORDER BY ModifiedDate DESC) rowNum
     FROM   BookingPassengerVersion
)
SELECT  cte.BookingID,
        ctePrev.NAME AS OldName,
        cte.NAME AS NewName,
        bh.Detail,
        bh.CreatedAgentCode,
        bh.ChangeDate
FROM    BH2 bh
        JOIN cteBookingPassengerVersion cte ON bh.BookingID = cte.BookingID AND bh.ChangeDate = cte.ModifiedDate
        LEFT JOIN cteBookingPassengerVersion ctePrev ON ctePrev.BookingID = cte.BookingId AND ctePrev.rowNum = cte.rowNum + 1
ORDER BY cte.BookingID, bh.ChangeDate DESC
```

**EDIT**
I updated the query to join back on date also and get all updates for all bookings

Update [New SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e8d2/15)

To filter the CTE by the BookingID's in BH2 you can either do

```
WITH cteBookingPassengerVersion AS
(
    SELECT  BookingID,
            RTRIM(
                CONCAT (
                  ISNULLLL(Title + ' ', ''),
                    ISNULL(FirstName + ' ', ''),
                    ISNULL(MiddleName + ' ', ''),
                    ISNULL(LastName, '')
                )
            ) AS NAME,
            ModifiedDate,
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY BookingID ORDER BY ModifiedDate DESC) rowNum
     FROM   BH2
     JOIN   BookingPassengerVersion ON BH2.BookingID = BookingPassengerVersion.BookingID
)
```

Or

```
WITH cteBookingPassengerVersion AS
(
    SELECT  BookingID,
            RTRIM(
                CONCAT (
                  ISNULLLL(Title + ' ', ''),
                    ISNULL(FirstName + ' ', ''),
                    ISNULL(MiddleName + ' ', ''),
                    ISNULL(LastName, '')
                )
            ) AS NAME,
            ModifiedDate,
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY BookingID ORDER BY ModifiedDate DESC) rowNum
     FROM   BookingPassengerVersion
     WHERE  BookingID IN (SELECT BookingID FROM BH2) 
)
```

you should try different things when dealing with large datasets.  I would even replace the cte with a temp table and see if it helps.  check your execution plan to see if you need any indexes also.

temp table instead of cte

```
SELECT  BookingID,
    RTRIM(
        CONCAT (
            ISNULLLL(Title + ' ', ''),
            ISNULL(FirstName + ' ', ''),
            ISNULL(MiddleName + ' ', ''),
            ISNULL(LastName, '')
        )
    ) AS NAME,
    ModifiedDate,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY BookingID ORDER BY ModifiedDate DESC) rowNum
INTO   #bpv
FROM   BookingPassengerVersion
WHERE  BookingID IN (SELECT BookingID FROM BH2) 

SELECT  cte.BookingID,
        ctePrev.NAME AS OldName,
        cte.NAME AS NewName,
        bh.Detail,
        bh.CreatedAgentCode,
        bh.ChangeDate
FROM    BH2 bh
        JOIN #bpv cte ON bh.BookingID = cte.BookingID AND bh.ChangeDate = cte.ModifiedDate
        LEFT JOIN #bpv ctePrev ON ctePrev.BookingID = cte.BookingId AND ctePrev.rowNum = cte.rowNum + 1
ORDER BY cte.BookingID, bh.ChangeDate DESC
```

Comment: I include the Sql Fiddle in your question, I think the returning rows arent correct yet. Doesnt show ADM Change

Comment: thanks.. query updated.. if you're not filtering this query and are going to be using tables with a lot or rows.  I would consider using a temp table or table variable to store the contents of cteBookingPassengerVersion.  I've run into performance issues using cte's instead of temp tables in large databases

Comment: user1221684 now it works for all Bookings, but the table `BookingPassengerVersion` has 259707998 records. The `WITH cteBookingPassengerVersion` needs to be limited by BookingID.

The SQL can not complete the query

Comment: It depends dates filter that was set before, I'm using a 1-year range and BH2 has 90 records

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: user1221684 thanks for the help ! I used the old `WITH cteBookingPassengerVersion`, Creating a temporary table to the `BookingPassengerVersion`. `SELECT * 
        INTO #BPV
  FROM BookingPassengerVersion
 WHERE BookingID IN (SELECT DISTINCT BookingID FROM #BH2);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e8d2/13)
I update the user1221684 answer to remove duplicated rows.

```
WITH cteBookingPassengerVersion AS
(
    SELECT  BookingID,
            RTRIM(
                CONCAT (
                    ISNULL(Title + ' ', ''),
                    ISNULL(FirstName + ' ', ''),
                    ISNULL(MiddleName + ' ', ''),
                    ISNULL(LastName, '')
                )
            ) AS NAME,
            AgentCode, -- add this line
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY BookingID ORDER BY ModifiedDate DESC) rowNum
     FROM   BookingPassengerVersion WHERE BookingID = 196162093
)
SELECT  cte.BookingID,
        ctePrev.NAME AS OldName,
        cte.NAME AS NewName,
        bh.Detail,
        bh.CreatedAgentCode,
        bh.ChangeDate,
        cte.rowNum,
        ctePrev.rowNum
FROM    BH2 bh
        JOIN cteBookingPassengerVersion cte ON (bh.BookingID = cte.BookingID and bh.CreatedAgentCode = cte.AgentCode) --Update this line
        LEFT JOIN cteBookingPassengerVersion ctePrev ON ctePrev.rowNum = cte.rowNum + 1
WHERE   cte.rowNum <= 2
```

Comment: I tested and it worked, but the `BookingId` can not be fixed, for each line `BH2` is necessary to do this ...... so I was trying to use the `Cross Apply`

Answer (score 0):

For this schema [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e20fb) , the expected result is:

```
BookingID | OldName                   | NewName                   | Detail                                              | CreatedAgentCode | ChangeDate    
----------|---------------------------|---------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------|------------------|--------------------------    
196162093 | MRS LUCIENE CORREA correa | MRS LUCIENE  CORREA       | MRS LUCIENE CORREA correa MRS LUCIENE  CORREA       | lclisboa         | 2015-01-18 13:29:35.130
196162093 | MRS LUCIENE CORREA LISBOA | MRS LUCIENE CORREA correa | MRS LUCIENE CORREA LISBOA MRS LUCIENE CORREA correa | VOMATOS          | 2015-01-18 13:25:26.420
195668459 | MR CARLOS PERHARDT JUNIOR | MR CARLOS  PERHARDT       | MR CARLOS PERHARDT JUNIOR MR CARLOS  PERHARDT       | azbussmann       | 2015-01-06 16:36:28.323
```

EDIT!

The final solution, I used the user1221684 answer creating a temporary table for the ´BookingPassengerVersion´

```
SELECT * 
    INTO #BPV
    FROM 
         BookingPassengerVersion
WHERE BookingID IN (SELECT DISTINCT BookingID FROM #BH2);

WITH cteBookingPassengerVersion AS
(
    SELECT  BookingID,
            RTRIM(
                CONCAT (
                    ISNULL(Title + ' ', ''),
                    ISNULL(FirstName + ' ', ''),
                    ISNULL(MiddleName + ' ', ''),
                    ISNULL(LastName, '')
                )
            ) AS NAME,
            ModifiedDate,
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY BookingID ORDER BY ModifiedDate DESC) rowNum
     FROM   #BPV
)
SELECT  cte.BookingID,
        ctePrev.NAME AS OldName,
        cte.NAME AS NewName,
        bh.Detail,
        bh.CreatedAgentCode,
        bh.ChangeDate
FROM    BH2 bh
        JOIN cteBookingPassengerVersion cte ON bh.BookingID = cte.BookingID AND bh.ChangeDate = cte.ModifiedDate
        LEFT JOIN cteBookingPassengerVersion ctePrev ON ctePrev.BookingID = cte.BookingId AND ctePrev.rowNum = cte.rowNum + 1
ORDER BY cte.BookingID, bh.ChangeDate DESC
```

Comment: i updated my original answer. it should give you the result you need